# writing a command transcript to file

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, io-redirection

Here is a script from [Mercurial issue 2743](http://mercurial.selenic.com/bts/issue2743). Call it `mq.sh`. I'm trying to get it to do the following things, on Debian squeeze.

1. Echo commands + standard output +
   standard error to a file.
2. Prefix with working directory.
   Sticking in $PWD doesn't work,
   as it presumably just keeps using
   the value from when it was first
   sourced.
3. Reset redirection back to normal
   standard output/error at the end.
   I'm not sure how to do this, but I
   imagine I'd have to use `exec`
   again.
4. I'm calling this with `sh mq.sh`.
   I'd like to do everything portably
   (if possible),
   and it seems exec is bash-specific,
   so I'm puzzled why this is working.
   Also `set -x xtrace` is probably bash
   specific as well. I got it from the
   Bash reference manual. Doesn't calling
   with `sh` run everything through `dash`
   on Debian?

1 currently works, I think. How do I do 2 and 3?
And can I have a clarification on 4?

```
export PS4="$PWD$ "
exec > mq.log 2>&1
export HG="hg-crew"
rm -r main clone

set -o xtrace
$HG init main
cd main
$HG init --mq
$HG qnew foo
echo a > a
$HG add
$HG qref
$HG ci --mq -Am.
cd ..
$HG qclone main clone
cd clone
$HG paths --mq
mv .hg/patches/.hg/hgrc{,.foo}
$HG paths --mq
$HG push --mq
echo b >> a
$HG qref
$HG ci --mq -m.
mv .hg/patches/.hg/hgrc.foo .hg/patches/.hg/hgrc
$HG push --mq
```

Comment: There's a command called [`script`](http://man.cx/script(1)) that might make your life easier.  `script — make typescript of terminal session
`

Comment: Resources if you're interested in shell portability: [Single Unix v3](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/), also available as [`susv3` on Debian](http://packages.debian.org/susv3); also older shell manuals. On Debian, both [`dash`](http://packages.debian.org/dash) and [`posh`](http://packages.debian.org/posh) are shell with few non-standard extensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exec` for file descriptors and `set -x` are portable; `xtrace` is not, but should actually be the same thing as `-x`.

To save and restore file descriptors, you do indeed use `exec` again.  You need to pick some unused descriptors, which usually means anything over 2, and redirect the originals to those, then redirect back at the end.

```
exec 20<&0 21>&1 22>&2
# do your redirections
# do whatever you wanted to have redirected
exec <&20 >&21 2>&22 20<&- 21>&- 22>&-
```

The last line first `dup()`s the saved file descriptors back where they came from, then closes (`&-`) the copies.  The closes are probably unnecessary but a good idea.

Also note that, if this is being run in its own shell, the redirections go away when the shell does.  You would only need to undo the redirection if you were using `.` (portable) or `source` (`bash`).

Comment: @geekosaur: Thanks. What about 2? Not sure what you mean by "xtrace is not, but should actually be the same thing as -x." So is `set -o xtrace` portable or not? I'll try to understand what the exec redirections are about. Do you have a good reference for this?

Comment: `set -o xtrace` is not portable, but its meaning in `bash` is the same as the portable version, `set -x`. Redirections you can find documented in http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections — note section 3.6.8 in particular. (3.6.9 is, however, `bash`-specific.)

Comment: [`set -o xtrace` has been standard for a while](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xcu/chap2.html#tag_001_014_011_002). Bourne only had `set -x` IIRC. `exec` redirections were already in Bourne as well, but only with single-digit file descriptors on some systems.

Comment: @Gilles: If `set -o xtrace` and `set -x` are equivalent and both portable, then which should be preferred? You are referencing Bourne as a precursor to the POSIX standard?

Comment: @Faheem: The [Bourne shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) was `/bin/sh` during Unix's formative years. The POSIX standard was mainly a compromise between the then-already-elderly Bourne shell and the more featureful, but not universally available [Korn shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korn_shell). The [Almquist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell) (the BSD replacement for the non-free Bourne shell) had `set -x` from day one, but didn't acquire `set -o` until later. So `set -x` will get you portability to more older (pre-POSIX) platforms.

Comment: @Gilles: Ah, I see. So this would have the advantage of being 'past-proofed'? I wonder if anyone uses these older shells any longer. I thought it was mostly bash and zsh these days.

Comment: @Faheem: Mostly bash and zsh for interactive use, but you can see the odd interactive ksh or tcsh question on this site. For scripting, there's a lot of ash, and people with old systems with an actual Bourne shell in `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 1):

For the working directory, try `PS4='+$PWD '`.  The single quotes mean it only gets expanded when it's about to be printed.  The first character of `PS4` can be printed multiple times, so you probably still want the `+` or at least a space at the start.

According to [POSIX definition of set](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/set.html), `set -x` and `set -o xtrace` are both supported.  The [dash man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/dash.1.html) says it's OK too.

Comment: Thanks. The single quote does indeed work. So, single quotes protect against expansion, so in this case, I guess the `'$PWD$ '` gets substituted as is wherever the `set -x` uses it, and then gets expanded there. Right? I'm not, however, clear on what you mean by `The first character of PS4 can be printed multiple times...`. Can you elaborate?